# Is it possible to disable client authentication for G Suite members (bound google sheet script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I have a bound google sheet script that create google drive folders, I use the sheet as a model, so the users can create new sheet based on that model. The problem is that every time that users create a new sheet they need to re-authentication for the oauth scope, because this is a copy of the original sheet.

I don't know what to do to cancel the authentication, someone have any idea please?

All users are member of the same domain (G Suite)

Comment: Is the copy created in the users account?

Comment: Yes, user create the copy in "my drive" then the script move the file to a shared drive.

Comment: I think that since the copy is in there drive and not some shared drive then they will have to authenticate it every time they make a new copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Cooper said on the comments:

> I think that since the copy is in there drive and not some shared drive then they will have to authenticate it every time they make a new copy.

This is indeed the case.

Every new copy of the sheet will create a new script, that will need to be authenticated again.

The only way to circumvent this is to have your script be triggered in some other fashion, like a [G Suite Add-On](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/overview) for instance.

Comment: Nice, I think I'll try the add-on as you said... Thank you all guys, I appreciate that!